# Mapbox choose custom map by ID

Tags: android, mapbox

How would one choose which Mapbox map to show? 
I have made the following custom map:
https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/ronenr.o2b7fleo/page.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9uZW5yIiwiYSI6ImNpZ2ZrbjB0ZjBzZTF2aWtybm1qb3p4cDkifQ.Dpn4r6OvARZ46k3zXrVMwA#10/33.3300/44.4486

How can I show it in my Android app using the Android SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from MapBox team, thanks, here it is:
Here is an example showing how to use custom raster tiles in your Android app - https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/custom-raster-style/.

In the activity, I will link to a custom json file:

```
mapView.setStyleUrl("http://www.odyeda.com/misc/mapbox-raster-v8.json");
```

Where the json file, in my case would be: (note the Url, which directs to my map)

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "sources": {
    "simple-tiles": {
      "type": "raster",
      "url": "mapbox://ronenr.o2b7fleo",
      "tileSize": 256
    }
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "simple-tiles",
      "type": "raster",
      "source": "simple-tiles"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case your map id would be `ronenr.o2b7fleo` Using it in the Android SDK:

```
MapView mapView = new MapView(context);
mapView.setAccessToken("Your Mapbox Access Token");
mapView.setTileSource(new MapboxTileLayer("ronenr.o2b7fleo"));
```

Take from the [quickstart in the repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-sdk-legacy/blob/mb-pages/QUICKSTART.md)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to be deprecated... The current mapView object does not seem to have a setTileSource method at all